# Можно ли обработать в runtime permission "Never ask again"?

Tags: android, runtime-permission

Нужно как-то обработать "Never ask again", то есть, если `user` ставит "больше не спрашивать", то нужно что-то показать, или отправить в настройки, или уведомить, что приложение не сможет работать. Есть метод `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` - его не нужно `paste` сюда, его задача вовсе другая. Она не обрабатывает "Never ask again"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил, непростая задача. Как раз с помощью данного метода `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` и решается, но нужно его обработать в `onRequestPermissionsResult` блоке `false`, то есть, где она выдает `false`.